# R Debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: r, function, debugging, rstudio, breakpoints

I'm running a script in R (using R Studio) which calls several nested functions (the script calls a function, which has some code, and then calls another function, etc). I need to debug a function which is several levels down. I can get into the first function called by the script by placing a breakpoint on the line with the function call, and then stepping into the function. However, when I try to repeat this step to get into the next function (by having a breakpoint at the line for the next function call), R just keeps running the code until it's done. Even using the 'continue' command which claims "continue execution until the next breakpoint is encountered."

I can get to the other functions by stepping through line by line, and then stepping into each function once I reach it, but it would take a very long time to get where I need to this way.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debug` is very convenient for problems of that sort. Say, you want to go through the function `myfun` step by step. Just run `debug(myfun)` before you run your code and it will behave as if you had a breakpoint on the first line of that function.

This works also, if the function is called from within other functions or if it is inside a package. In the latter case, it is particularly useful, because you can not just change the code of a function that comes from a package.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I had to play around with it a little to get what I wanted. You have to call `debug(myfunc)` for each nested function (not just the one you want to debug), and make sure `myfunc` has been sourced in the current function.

Comment: I think that `debug` should work on a function that is called within a function within a function ... without running it on the calling functions too. But there seems to be some limitations regarding functions in packages that I was not aware of.

Comment: If this is a function of a package (the internal one), how do I make sure it has been sourced?

Comment: You should be able to just use `debug()` on a function in a package as well. For instance: `debug(layer); ggplot(mtcars) + geom_line(aes(x = disp, y = cyl))`. If the function that you are interested in is not exported from the package, you have to use the `:::`-notation, e.g., `debug(ggplot2:::rename_aes)` together with the above `ggplot()`-call.