# debug R without sourcing

Tags: r, debugging

In R-studio, breakpoints don't trigger unless you click "source", which sources the entire file. This is inconvenient because at the start of my code, I usually import data and do other tasks which take a while to run.

I would like to be able to select some code and debug only that. This behavior is possible in MATLAB and VB. Is it possible to achieve this in R-studio or any other R IDE?

Comment: For example, in MATLAB, if you select some code and select "run" with a breakpoint within the selected section, that breakpoint will trigger and you enter the debugger.

Comment: Wow I wish this was the first R function I learned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if it is possible to debug your code on the top level (and I wish I knew if it was), but for functions you can try one of the following. Note that the debugger opens on a separate tab. This could be a little jarring at first.

1. Add `browser()` to your function.

```
function someFunction() {
  i <- 1
  browser() # stop here
  i + 1
}
```

2. Before running your function, flag it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805783/7669319)).

```
debug(someFunction) # flag function
someFunction()
undebug(someFunction) # unflag function

# alternatively use debugonce so your function is debugged only the first time
debugonce(someFunction)
someFunction() # debugged
someFunction() # not debugged
```